# How to make a custom HTML id by evaluating an expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I try to make a version of "tic tac toe" with AngularJS and be as minimalistic as possible. The only solution for my problem is to assign every button a unique ID (f+i).

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="f in [5,10,15]">
        <!-- numbers chosen for unique combos-->
        <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
            <button  ng-click="toTrue()" >
                <div >
                    {{getXO()}} 
                </div>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $scope.XObool=false;
 $scope.toTrue = function() {
     if(!$scope.XObool){
         $scope.XObool=true; 
     }
     else if($scope.XObool) {
         $scope.XObool=false;
     }
 };
 $scope.getXO = function(){
     if($scope.XObool){
         return 'X';
     }
     else {
         return 'O';
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-repeat` gives you several variables to work with, namely `$index`. In your case you'll want something like:

```
<button id="{{$index}}" ...>
```

More info on the [ng-repeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

**Second Option**

Use the `f` and `i` variables to create unique IDs.

```
<table ng-app>
  <tr ng-repeat="f in [5,10,15]" data-id="{{$index}}">
    <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
      <button id={{'id' + (i+f)}} ng-click="toTrue()">
        {{'id'+(i+f)}} 
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8kjxpcrr/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign each button a unique ID.

Instead, you can pass your f and i variables into your functions to track the board state:

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="f in [0,1,2]">
            <!-- numbers chosen for unique combos-->
        <td ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2]">
            <button ng-click="setState(f, i)">
            <div >
                {{ getXO(f,i) }} 
            </div>
        </button>
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m76w3kf5/

Answer (score 0):

try markup binding with {{}} or $index

```
<div id="{{someObject.id}}" class="some-class" ng-repeat="f in [ array ]">
..
</div>
```

or a slightly extended example with $index, listing thumbnails in array with clicks to reference position by index

```
<tr ng-repeat="array in thumbnails track by $index">
  <td ng-repeat="object in array track by object.id" 
      ng-click="tableClickHandler($index, object)">

    <img class="user-thumbnail" src="{{object.src}}">

  </td>
</tr>
```